# rails query with groups filtered by grouping object field

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to merge a N+1 queries situation wrapping into a grouping query instead.

I have a list of payments and for each of them I need a group of similar payments (same table), that have `created_at` date before the main group payment and NOT older than 6 months.

Other payments with created_at date more far in time need not to be in the group. Also the main payment needs not to be in the group (I'm just looking for the similar ones).

this is what I got so far:

```
payments_to_group_by = payments # a list of payments
Payment
  .where('created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', 
    6.months.ago, payments_to_group_by.map(&:created_at)
  )
  .where.not(id: payments_to_group_by.map(&:id))
  .group(payments_to_group_by.map(&:id))
```

I'm not sure where I can go from there. I think I should update the `group` parameters but I'm unsure how

Answer (score 0):

What I needed was a join from the `payments_to_group_by` and the `Payment` table, in this way the DB gives me a quantity of rows, and each has all the information I need.

all is left to do is filter and group them in the way I need, and got all the info I need. Even aggregate functions (avg, count, sum...) can come to help